# What is best practice for 'private' public URLs?

Tags: web-services, url, private, access-control

What is considered best practice to generate a URL that is publicly accessible, but shared via a side channel, so that it is in practice private to the group sharing it?

Something like:

http://example.com/club/XX-XX-XX-XX
http://example.com/club/YY-YY-YY-YY

Where XX-XX-XX-XX shared among one group, and YY-YY-YY-YY is shared by another group. If you have one valid code, it should not be easy to guess other valid codes.

No other security is required for the URL.

Comment: A random number would seem to be a good candidate, but how big should it be?

Answer (score 3):

[GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)s are always a good choice for unique IDs and are very easy to generate (but look ugly)

Comment: A guid contains 128 bits of information. If we assume a webserver can handle 10K requests/second, a guesser would need over 1x10^27 years to try each possibility in turn. That seems excessive, so something shorter than a GUID sounds better to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Amazon S3, they have time-limited exposed URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend generating a UUID.  You can use Java's java.util.UUID and URLEncode/Decode its textual representation if your back-end is in Java.  I'm sure there's an equivalent in .NET if you're using ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

To generate path part of URL use some form of hash (SHA1 will do). Of course randomized.
chmod the directory where files reside to 711 (`rwx--x--x`)

Answer (score 0):

A random sequence of alphanumeric characters would do the job. Characters choosen among 26 lower case letters, 26 upper case letters and 10 numbers repeated a dozen of times should largely be enough for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You're in a trade off between complexity and readability (or even memorability). GUID offers a 'unique' code that as has been mentioned is easy to generate however readability and memorability are low. Random character strings arbitrarily split might also offer a solution. Lastly, english words randomly chosen would be easier to memorise and communicate and would probably still offer the same level of isolation and protection.

After all, unless your users a particularly diligent and disable address history and browser history then the URL will be there for all to see who subsequently visit the machine.